# Unable to tap on Search on android keyboard using pressKeyCode(int) method

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, appium, mobile-automation

I am a beginner in Appium automation. The application I am testing, have this scenario where I need to tap on Search button from the native keyboard. I have tried with pressKeyCode method but getting this error-

```
The method pressKeyCode(int) is undefined for the type WebElement
```

I am using the following Environment-

```
Appium 1.4.16.1 with Java client 5.0.0-BETA8 
Selenium 3.4.0
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong? I have tried with earlier Java client for appium as well but nothing has worked so far. Also, is there any workaround other than the pressKeyCode to do this?

Comment: Please post the code that returned the error that you have described.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it: `((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKeyCode(84);`

For details about android keyevent:  [KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_SEARCH)